# Почему внутри функции не переопределяется переменная? JS

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function getYourHWA(idElement){
    let value = 0;
    idElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    value = +e.target.value; 
    console.log(value) // введенное значение в input
});
    console.log(value); // 0
};
```

Вопрос. Почему не сохраняется значение введенное в input. Как это значение вывести из функции?
Кстати, например если я сделаю так, то будет undefined, почему?

```
function getYourHWA(idElement){
    idElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let value = 0;
    value = +e.target.value;
    return value
    });
};
console.log(getYourHWA(input_block)) // undefined
```

Если можно вариант как это делают нормальные люди, а не как я учусь

Comment: Когда выполняется строчка - `console.log(value); // 0`?

Comment: `console.log(getYourHWA(input_block)) // undefined` - потому что функция `getYourHWA` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Обычно в вашем случае отсылают сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/ Если что-то будет неясно и захотите разобраться в теме асинхронности основательно, стоит прочитать этот раздел: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: Там где написал, забыл поставить вызов функции, после ее закрытия

Answer (score 0):

> Если можно вариант как это делают нормальные люди, а не как я учусь

Нормальные люди [документацию](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) читают.

```js
addEventListener('change', e => {
    value = +e.target.value;
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<input type='number'>
```